# jQuery: Is there a better way to switch two divs?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the following block of code to switch between two divs.

```
$('.btn-my-projects').click(function(e) {
    $('.my-projects').show();
    $('.all-projects').hide();
});

$('.btn-all-projects').click(function(e) {
    $('.my-projects').hide();
    $('.all-projects').show();
});
```

Obviously it works but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. Feels like it could be compressed down to one handler vs. two. If I use delegation I can make it a single handler but it will become longer, requiring a conditional check to see which button was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
function toggle(all) {
    $('.all-projects').toggle(all);
    $('.my-projects').toggle(!all);
}

$('.btn-my-projects').click(function() {
    toggle(false);
});

$('.btn-all-projects').click(function() {
    toggle(true);
});
```

If you want to get more terse:

```
function makeClickHandler(all) {
    return function () {
        $('.all-projects').toggle(all);
        $('.my-projects').toggle(!all);
    };
}

$('.btn-my-projects').click(makeClickHandler(false));
$('.btn-all-projects').click(makeClickHandler(true));
```

---

Alternately, you could take a completely different approach and put the link between which button shows & hides which div into the markup, using an HTML5 `data-*` attribute. Something like this:

```
<button class="project-control" data-show=".all-projects">
    Show all projects
</button>
<button class="project-control" data-show=".my-projects">
    Show my projects
</button>

<div class="project all-projects">...</div>
<div class="project my-projects">...</div>
```

with JavaScript like this:

```
$('.project-control').on('click', function () {
    var showSelector = $(this).data('show');
    $('.project').hide();
    $(showSelector).show();
});
```

N.B. in a real page, you would probably want to cache the selected elements.

Comment: To me this is not as readable as the original post.  It requires two head shakes.

Comment: I can read and understand it but I'm not sure it serves the purpose of writing less code. Still it's the best answer so far IMO

Comment: @robdodson personally, I like the last (data-driven-ish) approach since it means you don't need to write more JavaScript if you want to add more HTML (with more buttons/divs).

Comment: Matt Instead of glancing and understanding it, it requires me to re-look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use toggle() instead of show() and hide(). Then you could add a class .projects to the .my-projects and .all-projects divs and just toggle that selector.

Comment: how would you toggle the selector?

Comment: `$('.projects').toggle();` would do it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

What about using custom attributes?

Html:

```
<div class='my-projects'>my-projects</div>
<div class='all-projects'>all-projects</div>
<span class='toggler' hide='.all-projects' show='.my-projects'>btn-my-projects</span>
<span class='toggler' hide='.my-projects' show='.all-projects'>btn-all-projects</span>
```

and Javascript:

```
$('.toggler').click(function(e) {
    $($(this).attr('hide')).hide();
    $($(this).attr('show')).show();
});
```

Comment: This can be a good option if you have only one button. http://jsfiddle.net/ggmcj/

Comment: No, your code toggles the elements regardless of which button is clicked.

Comment: If I click the same button twice, for instance 'my projects', it will first turn my projects off and then turn it back on. That's not what I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are using is the way I would do it, but if you want to condense, may jquery's toggle would be of use to you http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: This is a comment not an answer, and by using toggle he'd have to control the state of at least one div.